# Orphan objects after error on SoapToObject

Tags: delphi, serialization, soap, memory-leaks, orphan

I have to call a method in a web service, that receives an object as parameter, but for many reasons I have to create a XML and then use SoapToObject to convert it to properly call the method.

The problem is, one of the property's method expects a integer value, but it's corresponding XML tag comes with a non-integer value(like "1-2" or "1/2"), and it causes an error at SoapToObject, that generates orphan objects inside it, then I can't kill it, so the leaks are growing and growing and causing the COM+ to freeze, requiring to kill the dllhost process manually

Class code example(please consider that all the creates and destructor are done and in the corret order):

```
TObject1GrandSon = class(TRemotable)
    ngs: string;
end;

TObject1Son = class(TRemotable)
    obj1g: TObject1GrandSon;
end;

TObject1 = class(TRemotable)
    ns1: string;
    obj1s: TObject1Son;
end;

TObject2Son = class(TRemotable)
    ns2: string;
end;

TObject2 = class(TRemotable)
    obj2s: TObject2Son;
end;

TObject3 = class(TRemotable)
    ns3: string;
end;

TMain = class(TRemotable)
    n1: string;
    obj1: TObject1;
    obj2: TObject2;
    n2: integer;
    obj3: TObject3;
end;

TReturn = class(TRemotable);
```

Respective XML example:

```
XMLEntry:= '
    <main>
        <n1>Text 1</n1>
        <obj1>
            <ns1>Text 2</ns1>
            <obj1s>
                <obj1g>
                    <ngs>Text 3</ngs>
                </obj1g>
            </obj1s>
        </obj1> 
        <obj2>
            <obj2s>
                <ns2>Text 4</ns2>
            </obj2s>
        </obj2>
        <n2>1-1</n2>
        <obj3>
            <ns3>Text 5</ns3>
        </obj3>
    </main>';
```

Code calling example:

```
var
    rio: THTTPRIO;
    Entry: TMain;
    Return: TReturn;
    iXML: IXMLDocument;
begin
    iXML:= NewXMLDocument;
    iXML.LoadFromXML(XMLEntry);

    rio:= THTTPRio.Create(nil);
    Entry:= TMain.Create;           
    try
        Entry.SOAPToObject(iXML.DocumentElement, iXML.DocumentElement, rio.Converter);
        ws:= GetWS_PortType(false, url, rio);

        Return:= nil;
        try
            Return:= ws.Method1(Entrada);   
        finally
            Return.Free;
        end;
    finally
        Entry.Free;
    end;
end;
```

So, considering all the codes above, the Exception "'1-1'' is not a valid integer value" will be raised, and then the objects that have been already created "obj1"(including the correspondent objects "obj1s" and "obj1g") and "obj2" will be orphans and will be shown on the MemoryLeaks window.

There are any fix to it? There is a way to change the serealization method? There are some directives that can be changed at initialization that won't let orphan objects?